# Quick Hash Table using Chaining

Tags: hash, chaining

Attempting to better understand chaining on a hashtable. Seeking a simple table that hashes a value and only associates one integer to the value hashed. Here is sample code of the problem in question...

```
      /* hash string value return int */
      public int hashFunction(String D) {
          char[] Thing = D.toCharArray();
          for(int i=0; i < Thing.length; i++){
             index += Thing[i]; }
          return index % TABLE_SIZE;          
      }

      /* hash string value return void */
      public void hashFunction(String D) {
        char[] Thing = D.toCharArray();
        for(int i=0; i < Thing.length; i++){
         index += Thing[i];}
        int hash = index % TABLE_SIZE;
        if(table[hash] == null){
          table[hash] = new HashEntry( Level,  Value );
        }        
        else{
          table[hash].setNext(nd);
        }
      }

      /* miscellaneous code snippet */
      if(table[hash] == null){
        table[hash] = new HashEntry();
      }

      else if (Data.compareTo("VAR") == 0) {
          Data = inFile.next();   
            char[] Thing = Data.toCharArray();
            for(int i=0; i < Thing.length; i++){
            hash += Thing[i];}
            hash = hash % TABLE_SIZE;           
            hm.setIntoHashTable(hash);      
                Data = inFile.next();
                    if(Data.compareTo("=") == 0) {
                    Data = inFile.next();
                    int value = Integer.parseInt(Data);
                    hm.getIntoHashTable(he.setValue(value));
                }
      }
```

Comment: you can create `int generateHash(String D)` and `int insertIntoHashTable(String D)`. `generateHash` is your hash function. `insertIntoHashTable` will first call `generateHash` and then have insert logic

Comment: can you describe bit more about your hashfunction? What is the `int level` and what is the other int you talking about?

Comment: Please don't shout in your question...

Comment: And please don't deface the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well the chaining occurs when you have collision in the indexes.

Lets assume you have a TABLE_SIZE=10

Now you have to store string `abc`, so you get hash as `4`

Now when you gonna store string `cba`, you end up with same hash `4`

So now to store `cba` at the same index, you will create and store a List at index `4`.

The List will contain both `abc` and `bca`. This List is called `chain` and this process of storing multiple values at the same hash is called `Chaining`.

Pseudo code look like:

```
if(table[hash] == null)
  table[hash] = new ArrayList<HashEntry>();//APPEND ON TO THE LOCATION ALREADY THERE!
table[hash].add(new HashEntry());
```

The table will be declared as:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
List<HashEntry>[] table = new List[TABLE_SIZE];
```

You might have to suppress warning as arrays and generics dont go smoothly.

Comment: can you describe bit more about your hashfunction? What is the int level and what is the other int you talking about?